# dynamically updating ContentPlaceHolder from hyperlinks

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have a master page which gives me 2 contentplaceholders (apart from the header one)
1 is a left gutter, 1 is the main body square on the right of the gutter.

In the webform, my gutter has an accordion control, with each panel having a bunch of hyperlinks.
I would like for each hyperlink to control the "form" inside the main body's contentplaceholder.

I am guessing something to the effect of having multiple UserControls, and webform has an updatepanel inside the main section, and I dynamically assign the UserControls depending on which hyperlink was clicked.

I am not sure how to google for this.

I could just have lots of panels, all invisible, and the hyperlink calls some jquery to make a certain panel visible, but this seems very inefficient.

Can someone help me with a slicker solution?
Or am i over thinkiing this and should just have an aspx page for each hyperlink? But then I will lose my space in the accodian.....
note - this is asp.net webforms, not mvc

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have to use `HyperLinks`? Can you use `LinkButtons` instead?

Comment: linkbuttons are good too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the full details of what you're trying to do, but with a `LinkButton` you can use the click event handler to call a method or set a property in the master page:

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Master.TogglePlaceHolder("Some Criteria");
}
```

To use this approach you will need a strongly typed reference to the master page, which you can take care of in the page directive like this:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Themes/Default.master" %>
```

And then in the master page, just make sure that the method or property is accessible:

```
public void TogglePlaceHolder(string criteria)
{
    //perform your logic here
}
```

Comment: thanks. that's helpful! but the 2nd half of my prob, is i dynamically want to assign a usercontrol to my contentplaceholder without a page refresh. something like - contentplaceholder.clear, contentplaceholder.add(myusercontrol) etc etc

Comment: Unless you plan on using AJAX, there's no way to avoid a refresh. If you're okay with using AJAX though, you should be able to achieve this by wrapping the `PlaceHolder` and the `LinkButton` in an update panel (or separate update panels if necessary).

Comment: part 2 of my answer is [stackoverflow.com/questions/213429/… [1]: stackoverflow.com/questions/213429/… sorted!